# How to close the sqldatareader within Using statement?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqldatareader

I'd like to use this code to verify if duplication occurs or not before saving the data to the database. How am I supposed to close the `sqldatareader`? (As what the error shows me)

```vb
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PC85AAIEw\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True"
cmd.Connection = con

con.Open()

Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Profile WHERE RollNo=@RollNo AND Name=@Name"
Dim cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery, con)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RollNo", TextBox1.Text)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox2.Text)

Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows Then
        MessageBox.Show("User already registered! Please try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Else
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Profile VALUES ('" & rollno & "' , '" & name & "' , '" & gender & "' , '" & address & "' , '" & phoneno & "' , '" & datereg & "' , '" & faculty & "' , '" & course & "' , '" & semester & "')"
        MessageBox.Show("Profile has been successfully registered!", "Thank you", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
End Using
con.Close()
```

Comment: `As what the error shows me` <= What error? You didn't post one. The data reader instance is *after* the using block's inner code is finished running.

Comment: I think I see your problem. You must complete the execution of the data reader before you try to execute another command on the *same* connection. Also you need to use parameters on your insert just like you did on your select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error are referring to is because you must complete the execution of the data reader before you try to execute another command on the same connection.

Additionally there are some issues with your code:

- It is strongly recommended you use and then dispose of SqlConnections as you use them, do not try to reuse these globally in your application. The ado.net SQL Server client library will handle connection pooling for you by default.
- You need to use parameters with your insert just like you did on your select.
- [Do not to use `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) when adding your parameters, instead use the constructor and also specify the sql data type. If `RollNo` is a number (like integer) then you should pass the value as an integer to your parameter. I assumed it was a string stored in a `varchar`.
- Wrap all types that implement `IDisposable` in `Using` statements to ensure resources are always released. (*In case any one wants to nitpick, no it is not required for `SqlCommand` in this case*.)

```vb
Dim recordExists As Boolean
Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC85AAIEw\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True")
Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT RollNo FROM Profile WHERE RollNo=@RollNo AND Name=@Name", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RollNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text

    con.Open()
    Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        recordExists = reader.HasRows
    End Using
End Using
End Using

If recordExists Then
    MessageBox.Show("User already registered! Please try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
Else
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC85AAIEw\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True")
    Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Profile (RollNo, Name) VALUES (@RollNo, @Name)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RollNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Profile has been successfully registered!", "Thank you", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Using
    End Using
End If
```

Comment: Yes this answer is helpful. Thanks! However, what is the issue between `Parameters.Add` and `Parameters.AddWithValue`? I know both are similar which `Parameters.AddWithValue` doesn't required to specify the data type. And before this, you were using `Parameters.AddWithValue` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @no0b3 - The main issue is that the sql data types are not explicitly set. This means that there could be issues when comparing varchar with nvarchar or conversion of a string to an int etc. (see the linked article for more details). That code more easily allows for bugs to be introduced which don't manifest themselves until run time and maybe only with a specific set of circumstances.

Comment: @no0b3 - you are right in that I had initially copied your code that used `AddWithValue`, after I edited my answer the 2nd time I realized that this was there and changed it to what is there now with the Sql data type being specified explicitly.

Comment: Since data type will be specified within `Parameter.Add` command, so I could just skip the initial declarations for all the variables right?

Comment: @no0b3 - I am not sure I follow. The [SqlParameter constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameter__ctor_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_) takes a parameter `SqlDbType` which is the parameter type that the value will be assigned to. What is the `initial declaration` you are referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to the declarations of the local variables before actually use it.

Comment: @no0b3 - can you give me a specific instance of a variable you are talking about? Do keep in mind that if you are referring to `con` or `cmd` that these are declared as a part of the `Using` block so they only have scope inside the `Using` block. The same goes for anything declared inside those blocks, as soon as the run time exists the block scope those declared variables also lose scope. This is also why `recordExists` is declared outside but is assigned inside a `Using` block.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I'm referring to local variables declaration like `Dim rollno As String` etc and then declare it again as `VarChar` in `Parameters.Add`? Is it actually a necessary practice?

Comment: @no0b3  I don't know about `Dim rollno As String`, it is not found anywhere in the question (or my answer). The value is coming from `TextBox1.Text` and I can probably safely assume that has to stay as that is the source for the value.

Comment: I found one issue with `cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RollNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text)`Error shows: `The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not Boolean objects.`

Comment: @no0b3 - sorry about that, see the update which fixes that.

Comment: @no0b3 Note that it is good practice to specify the database column size for string-type variables, e.g. if [Name] is declared as VARCHAR(30) then you would use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = TextBox2.Text`. It helps SQL Server keep the size of its execution plan cache down as it doesn't have to make a new execution plan for each length of string if you specify it. In this case, it will make little difference, but if you do it automatically then when it really matters you will have done it already.

Comment: Thanks @Igor for your huge help. I'll give you a credit in my project. I'm sure appreciate your guidance. Keep it up!

Answer (score -2):

if you are using **using**  then not need to close. because it internally close all connection. The code would be like this

```
 using(var con=new Sqlconnection("Data Source=PC85AAIEw\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True")){
cmd.Connection = con

con.Open()

Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Profile WHERE RollNo=@RollNo AND Name=@Name"
Dim cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery, con)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RollNo", TextBox1.Text)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox2.Text)

Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows Then
        MessageBox.Show("User already registered! Please try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Else
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Profile VALUES ('" & rollno & "' , '" & name & "' , '" & gender & "' , '" & address & "' , '" & phoneno & "' , '" & datereg & "' , '" & faculty & "' , '" & course & "' , '" & semester & "')"
        MessageBox.Show("Profile has been successfully registered!", "Thank you", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
End Using
con.Close()}
```

Comment: you need to update only first line.  
using(var con=new Sqlconnection("Data Source=PC85AAIEw\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True"))